# SQL - store count in same column based on different values in multiple column

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I have a table (TableA) which contains three columns

Sample rows given below

| ID | METRIC | TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | A | J |
| X | A | J |
| X | A | K |
| X | B | K |
| Y | A | J |
| Y | B | J |
| Y | B | L |

In the output I need one column for count of rows and distinct count of ids based on the following criteria:

1. Count all rows of input data as TBL_TOT, count distinct IDs from the input table
2. For each value of column Metric, count the total records and count the distinct IDs.
3. For each value of column Type, count the total records and count the distinct IDs.

Output will look like this:

| VALUE | COUNT | DISTINCT_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TBL_TOT | 7 | 2 |
| A | 4 | 2 |
| B | 3 | 2 |
| J | 4 | 2 |
| K | 2 | 1 |
| L | 1 | 1 |

Currently I am doing a Union all for all different cases like below:

```
SELECT 'TBL_TOT',COUNT(*) AS COUNT,COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS DISTINCT_OUNT
FROM TABLEA

UNION ALL

SELECT METRIC,COUNT(*) AS COUNT,COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS DISTINCT_OUNT
FROM TABLEA
GROUP BY METRIC

UNION ALL

SELECT TYPE,COUNT(*) AS COUNT,COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS DISTINCT_OUNT
FROM TABLEA
GROUP BY TYPE
;
```

Is there any other efficient way of getting this result other than UNION ALL and PIVOT/UNPIVOT?

If not, then if we ignore the tbl_tot part, can the bottom two unions be done in some other way?

The actual dataset is huge and query execution is taking too long.

Comment: simply no chance

Comment: What's wrong with the current method? Also, SQL syntax can vary a lot by vendor and version. Which dbms are you using? Please [edit] the question tags ...

Comment: This is the straight-forward way to solve this. There probably is no better alternative. (If your DBMS happens to be Oracle, you might be able to produce this output with the MODEL clause, but I am not versed in this clause, and it is the only DBMS I know of featuring this.)

Comment: What if we have to ignore the tbl_tot part. Can the remaining two unions be done any other way?

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the way you're doing it now?

Comment: I have just added sample rows in the question. The actual dataset is quite huge. Union all is causing more time for query execution. Thats the problem